# This webpage is using significant memory: how to stop it appearing?

Tags: macos, safari, mojave, memory

[image]

> This webpage is using significant memory. Closing it may improve the responsiveness of your Mac.

This banner appears at the top of some websites I use sometimes.

If I close it, it reappears again momentarily.

How can I force it to either

- never appear
- or only appear once and not re-appear after I've manually closed it

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8353302

Comment: @Daniil Manokhin, The linked answer talks about force quitting Safari and is not at all relevant to the question asked as he's able to close the given window normally! He's asking how to force the message "This webpage is using significant memory. Closing it may improve the responsiveness of your Mac." to either  "never to appear" or "only appear once and not re-appear after I've manually closed it"

Comment: <poke> I wish I could banish that warning, too. It appears on a site I use often, yet the memory & responsiveness of my mac don't really seem affected. Likewise for the warning about the page being reloaded as it was using too many resources. Fine - you don't have to continually tell me that.

Comment: This is still an issue for me, it often appears when watching Disney+ for example, and if I click to dismiss it it comes back a few minutes later. My solution is... to use Chrome. But I don't like it. I would like to be able to permanently dismiss this warning, regardless of the quantity of memory the page is actually using. I hope someone finds a way eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The question assumes that the feature ***can*** be configured or disabled: and that is by no means certain. The answer may well be "*You can't"*.

The options will only exist if the Safari devs specifically coded changes to this behaviour. There are no relevant parameters in Safari's Preferences, nor in the Developer menu.

That only leaves the possibility of an (undocumented) plist key, which would require searching through the binary files of the app looking for likely text strings.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the answer you're looking for but I've discovered my MacBook Air (10.14 macOS Mojave) runs faster and I have a smoother web experience when I use Brave or a browser other than Safari.

Comment: That is unusual. I've read and experienced that Safari gives by far the best overall laptop responsiveness and longest battery life.